# how to merge two sql conditional statements

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    table name: game
    id   player   keeper
    1    a            b
    2    c            d
    3    a            e
    4    c            b
```

condition_one: where player=a  and keeper=b
condition_two: where player=b  and keeper=a

i want to achieve: condition_one or condition_two
does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you consider using `or`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `or` statement:

```
select *
from game
where ((player = 'a' and keeper = 'b') or (player = 'b' and keeper = 'a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use tuples:

```
select g.*
from game g
where (player, keeper) in ( ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'));
```